# How to prevent data masking in SQL2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, data-masking

When I use dynamic data masking in SQL2016

```
(FUNCTION = 'partial(1,"XXXXXXX",0)')
```

the select statement returns the value

`"XXXXXXX"`

For empty fields which is not a valid value for my process.

Is there any way to use data masking but only for fields with values (not spaces and not nulls)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` expression, which returns empty string when the field in question is either `NULL` or contains nothing but spaces:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(REPLACE(field, ' ', ''), '') <> ''
         THEN field
         ELSE '' END AS field_masked
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanx for the help. I wonder if there is an automated way. I want to avoid extended refactoring Of my procedures....

Comment: You may mark this answer correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: Not really. I find it strange to mask an empty field and  write Code after in order to fix it. What the use of It?